# Debugging XSL compile error

Tags: xslt

We have a Java application that consumes an  XSL file.  I added a "wrap" tag, which I sure thought was valid, to our sheet and how I'm getting an error when the application runs that it could not complile the XSL.  Is there a a tool I can get to compile the sheet and give me more specifics on what it's not liking about it?

Comment: I agree with Martin, Saxon would be an excellent way to get more specific errors about the XSL. If you still have trouble figuring out what's wrong, show us Saxon's error and some of the XSL, especially the part you changed.

Answer (score 1):

Which XSLT processor do you use in your Java application code? The main Java XSLT processors like Saxon 6.5 for XSLT 1.0 or Saxon 9 for XSLT 2.0/3.0 or Xalan-Java for XSLT 1.0 have command line applications emitting error messages details on the command line. So usually running them that way gives you good diagnostics. If you want more comfort and a GUI to work with choose an XML IDE like Oxygen or Stylus Studio.

Comment: We're using this as a part of Appache's FOP print formatter.  I think it's classes in the fop.jar that are doing the work for us.  I don't know that I was looking for something I could download.  I'll look into the two you mention.